# LeetCode 49: Group Anagrams

Tags: java, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, hash-map

I'm exceeding the time limit for a 10,000 word [test case](http://pastebin.com/x9jntRUW) provided on [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/anagrams/):

> Given an array of strings, group anagrams together.
>
> For example, given: `["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"]`,
>   Return:
>
> ```
> [
>   ["ate", "eat","tea"],
>   ["nat","tan"],
>   ["bat"]
> ]
> ```
>
> Note: All inputs will be in lower-case.

Any suggestions on how I could speed this up a little bit?

```
public HashMap<String, List<Integer>> createMap(String[] strs)
{
  HashMap<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();

    for(String s: strs)
    {
     char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
     Arrays.sort(charArray);
     String sortedString = new String(charArray);

     if(map.containsKey(sortedString))
     {
        List<Integer> pos = map.get(sortedString);
        pos.add(Arrays.asList(strs).indexOf(s));
        map.put(sortedString, pos);
     }

    else
    {
        List<Integer> pos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        pos.add(Arrays.asList(strs).indexOf(s));
        map.put(sortedString, pos);
    }
  }

  return map;
}

public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {

  HashMap hm = createMap(strs);

  List<List<String>> anagrams = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

  for(Object k: hm.keySet())
  {
    String key = k.toString();
    ArrayList pos = (ArrayList)hm.get(key);

    List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Object p : pos)
    {
      int idx = Integer.parseInt(p.toString());
      a.add(strs[idx]);
    }
    anagrams.add(a);
  }
  return anagrams;
}
```

Comment: Please include the description of the programming-challenge into the question so the reviewers can see what you're trying to do and why.

Answer (score 7):

#### Why so slow

It's important to consider the time complexity of all the operations in your program.

Take a closer looks at this part I extracted from your code:

> ```
> for(String s: strs)
> {
>  // ...
>
>     pos.add(Arrays.asList(strs).indexOf(s));
> ```

For each `s`, converting a `String[]` to a `List<String>`, in order to use the `indexOf` method to find the index of `s`? That doesn't sound so good. How about making that a counting loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
    // ...

    pos.add(i);
```

But why use indexes at all? Why not make this method return a `Map<String, List<String>>` instead?

```
for (String s : strs) {
    // ...

    pos.add(s);
```

If you do that, then the implementation of the other method becomes simply:

```
public List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {
    return new ArrayList<>(createMap(strs).values());
}
```

#### Good practices

The code violates many good practices and common conventions:

- Never use raw types, for example use `HashMap<String, List<String>>` instead of just `HashMap` without type parameters
- Prefer to declare variables with interface types, for example `Map<String, List<String>>` instead of `HashMap<String, List<String>>`
- Use the diamond operator `<>` when possible, for example `new HashMap<>` instead of `new HashMap<String, List<String>>`
- Use consistent indentation, and please place braces they way I did in my examples above

Answer (score 2):

Jianmin commented on my answer to a similar question here: [Grouping anagrams](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/80681/31503) and it got me thinking about the problem, and also reading this solution.

Janos has some good comments, but I wanted to point out three additional things:

### computeIfAbsent

Java Map instances now have the `computeIfAbsent` function. Code like:

> ```
>  if(map.containsKey(sortedString))
>  {
>     List<Integer> pos = map.get(sortedString);
>     pos.add(Arrays.asList(strs).indexOf(s));
>     map.put(sortedString, pos);
>  }
>
> else
> {
>     List<Integer> pos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
>     pos.add(Arrays.asList(strs).indexOf(s));
>     map.put(sortedString, pos);
> }
> ```

should instead be:

```
List<Integer> pos = map.computeIfAbsent(sortedString, k -> new ArrayList<>());
pos.add(Arrays.asList(strs).indexOf(s));
```

Of course, you should be using String values and not Integers, as Janos indicated, but the idea is to only have one call in to the Map. See the docs here: [computeIfAbsent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)

### function extraction

Your code to compute the "key" from the word, should be extracted in to a separate function. There should be a function:

```
public static final String keyOf(String word) {
    char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    return new String(chars);
}
```

It clearly is separate, isolated logic, and should be maintained as such.

### Streams

Streams have been around for a while, and you should become familiar with them.

I tool the liberty of "solving" the problem using streams, and the code is relatively neat, and concise:

```
public static final List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(Stream<String> stream) {
    Map<String, List<String>> mapped = stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> keyOf(w)));
    return new ArrayList<>(mapped.values());
}
```

I have put that in to an ideone page here: https://ideone.com/qLiA8c (that ideone code also has code to format it "pretty" ... like the examples above).

Comment: These are all very good and helpful points. I'm not so familiar with Streams and Generics functions, but I will incorporate these changes. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**Make Java code more readable, ready to review**

I strongly agree with code review conducted by Janos, code review is not just to share you a workable solution. You also have to learn ways to make code more readable, practice better way using Java language in your case.

**Use O(N) solution to generate key, avoid \$O(NLogN)\$ Sorting algorithm**

The idea to avoid timeout issue is to generate a key for each anagram group using \$O(N)\$ time complexity, instead of naive one by sorting the string. To take advantage of alphabetic number only has constant of size \$26\$, go through the string once, one char a time, to record the number of occurrence, like a counting sort. Here is [the C# code](https://gist.github.com/jianminchen/fb6f90e0e227928805f76357079a6b01), pass all test cases on leetcode online judge.

Here is the anagram hashed key algorithm in C#, most of important decision is to choose a more efficient sort - counting sort instead of comparison based sorting:

```
    /* O(n) solution 
     * abc 
     * hashed to key:
     * 01-11-11
     * 0 stands for a, 1 is count of a
     * further simplify the key:
     * 1-1-1
     * first 1 is count of a, 
     * second 1 is count of b, 
     * third 1 is count of c
     * 
     */
    public static string ConvertHashKeys(string input)
    {
        if (input == null || input.Length == 0)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        int[] countAlphabetic = new int[26];

        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            countAlphabetic[c - 'a']++;
        }

        return String.Join("-", countAlphabetic);
    }
```